# Error when customising JOptionPane Message Dialog Buttons

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm receiving the error: `no suitable method found for showMessageDialog` when trying to customise a showMessageDialog button to say "Start" instead of OK.

This is the code:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, radioPanel, "Start Game", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new String[]{"Start"});
```

Could someone point out why I might be receiving this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: there are no `showMessageDialog` which will accept six parameters. Check out this doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 overloads of `showMessageDialog`:

- [One with 2 arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-)
- [One with 4 arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-)
- [One with 5 arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-)

You are trying to call this method with 6 arguments, so none apply. You need to carefully read the documentation to decide which one you require.